# How to execute shell script on top of spark

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop, apache-spark

How to execute shell script on top spark.
script is below.

```
#!/bin/bash

load data into local path $source $dest
```

Comment: This is too vague question, are you trying to save data that is generated in spark application to local directory?

Comment: Or are you trying to execute a local download from **HDFS** on each node?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oozie , then have a two step workFlow

> 1. a bash action
> 2. the spark job.

In bash action execute the expected command.

Else you can do the same stuff by using **hdfs client in your java code** before submitting the spark job. sparkContext.submit.

Please follow for detailed understanding http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/how-to-submit-spark-job-through-oozie/

Comment: I have the script in edge node i am trying to load the data into hive (152)tables usually it takes 3 to 4 hours but now a days it takes more than a day. By using the script i am deploying th all the tables and i am submitting the jobs to falcon.

Comment: Script:START_TIME=$(date +%s)
  hive_tblname=$sourcesystemlower"_"$countrylower"_rowcounts"
  hive --hivevar OPS_DB="$DB_OPS" --hivevar HIVE_TABLE="$hive_tblname" --hivevar PARTITION_NAME="$preprocessing_date" -f $APP_BASE_PATH/preprocessing/sql/threshold.hql > $preprocessed_path/temp/ops_tab.list